# Formatting an issue with my Do loop

Tags: java

I am having a bit of an issue trying to solve the redundancy in my code. My do loop checks to see if the user input is not equal to "bye" if it is not equal to bye then it does all what that is intended. But when I get to "Is there anything else you want to know" I get stuck and don't know how to run the program again to call the parse file( ) so I had to duplicate

```
     System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);
```

Is there any way I could make this program work without duplicating the above code?
         public static void getinput() throws IOException {

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */

    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    do {
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);

        System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);

    } while (!input.contains("bye")); 
    System.out.println("have a good day");

}
```

Comment: do you want to want to do the same stuff when the user types "> " and "is there anything you want to know?"

Comment: ">" is just like a cursor for an input. I just want to go back into the do loop. Do i sysout something where the user types yes/no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try this

```
public static void getinput() throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */

    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    for (;;) {
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);

        if (input.equals("bye"))
            break;

        System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);
//might add another checker here
//if (input.equals("bye"))
        //  break;

    }
    System.out.println("have a good day");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean flag=false;
do {
    if(!flag)
        System.out.print("> ");
    else
        System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");

        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        parseFile(input);
        flag=!flag;
    } while (!input.contains("bye"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should get the first input outside the loop then at the beginning of the loop check whether the `input` contains `"bye"` and then go into the loop. So this is going to change your loop from `do - while` to a `while` loop. I illustrate it below:

```
System.out.println("Welcome ");
System.out.println("What would you like to know?");
System.out.print("> ");
input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

while (!input.contains("bye")) {
    parseFile(input);

    System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
} ;
```